# When does order convergence imply topological convergence?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, order-theory, topological-vector-spaces, nets

Let $V$ be a locally convex topological vector space (or even a Banach space), equipped with a closed partial order, or equivalently, a closed positive cone. 
It is well known that any directed net $\{v_\alpha\}$ tending to $v$ *topologically* also tends to $v$ order-theoretically, i.e. $\sup_\alpha v_\alpha = v$.

Under which condition is the converse true? That is, suppose that a directed net $\{v_\alpha\}$ has order-supremum $v$. Then under which conditions (on $\{v_\alpha\}$ and/or on the topology and order of $V$) does $\{v_\alpha\}$ tend to $v$ topologically? Are there known results (and/or counterexamples)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Counterexample

In $\ell^1$, let the positive cone be $$P=\left\{x: \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{k!}\ge 0, \  n=1,2,\dots\right\}$$ This is a proper cone since the only way for all these partial sums to be zero is when $x_k=0$ for all $k$. It is also closed, being an intersection of closed half-spaces.

Consider a sequence $z_j = -j^{-1}e_{j}  +  e_{j+1}$. It satisfies $z_j<0$ because
$$
-\frac{1}{j\, j!} + \frac1{(j+1)!} < 0
$$
It is also increasing, as
$$
z_{j+1}-z_{j} = \frac{1}{j}e_j - \frac{j+2}{j+1}e_{j+1}+e_{j+2}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{1}{j\,j!} -  \frac{j+2}{(j+1)(j+1)!} 
 = \frac{(j+1)^2 - j(j+2)}{j(j+1)(j+1)!} = \frac{1}{j(j+1)(j+1)!} > 0
$$
If $z\ge z_j$ for all $j$, then necessarily $z\ge 0$. Thus $z_j$ converge to $0$ in the sense of order. But $\|z_j\|_1>1$, so the convergence is not topological.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but one thing is still not clear to me: why does the definition of supremum imply that the $v_\alpha$ are eventually in $S_{x,v}$? Could you please explain that step a bit more?

Comment: Also, could you please give me a reference?

Comment: My thinking was: since $x < v$, the element $x$ cannot be an upper bound for the net. Hence, there exists an element of the net greater than it. And since it is directed, all subsequent ones are greater than $x$, too.  (Also, I don't know anything about ordered vector spaces, and don't have references either.  _Caveat lector_.)

Comment: Well, that would work in a total order, but unfortnuately not in a partial order. For example, the sequence $(-1/n,0)$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (with its componentwise order) tends to $0$ order-theoretically (and topologically, but suppose we didn't know). Now for any $\varepsilon>0$ take $x=(0,-\varepsilon/2)$, which is below zero and within distance $\varepsilon$ from zero. The whole "segment" from $x$ to $0$ is also within distance $\varepsilon$ from zero, but it never intersects our original sequence.

Comment: You are right of course. A counterexample is all I can offer.